# white spaces on the all sides

Tags: theme-development

I am new to wordpress and this is the first html website I converted. After I converted my page to a wordpress theme, I notice that there is a white space on all sides of my page. This only happened after converting because my original html page doesn't have white spaces. I have *{padding:0; margin:0;} on my css but it doesn't seem to work on wordpress.

header.php

```
 <?php
/**
 * The template for displaying the header
 *
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Fifteen
 * @since Twenty Fifteen 1.0
 */
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>My Theme</title>
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>" type="text/css"     
media="screen" />
<?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
<?php 

if(is_home()):
    $awesome_classes = array('awesome-class', 'my-class');
else:
    $awesome_classes = array('no-awesome-class');
endif;

?>
<body <?php body_class($awesome_classes); ?>>

<div class="container">
    <h2 class="logo">MY WEBSITE</h2>
    <?php wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location'=>'primary')); ?>
```

footer.php

```
</div>
<footer class="thefooter">
<p>Copyright 2015 My Website - All Rights Reserved</p>
<?php //wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location'=>'secondary')); ?>
</footer>
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

style.css

```
/*
Theme Name: My Theme
Theme URL: wordpress.com/index.php
Author: Rendell Lasola
Description: This is an awesome theme
License: GNU General Public License v2 or later
License URI: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
Tags: black, white, responsive, one-column, two-columns, featured-images,  
custom-menu, custom-header, post-formats 
*/
*{
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
font-family: Arial;
list-style-type: none;
}

.container{
width: 100%;
max-width: 1020px;
margin: auto;
}

h1,.widget-title{
display: none;
}

h2.logo{
float: left;
font-family: Azedo;
font-size: 2em;
padding: 10px;
}

#menu-navigation{
float: right;
padding: 10px;
}


#menu-navigation li{
display: inline-block;
font-weight: bold;
padding: 15px; 
}

#menu-navigation li a{
text-decoration: none;
font-family: Arial;
font-weight: bold;
color: #2C3E50;
-webkit-transition: 0.4s all;
-moz-transition: 0.4s all;
-ms-transition: 0.4s all;
-o-transition: 0.4s all;
transition: 0.3s all;
}

#menu-navigation li a:hover{
color: #1E8BC3;
}

.container .jumbotron{
background: url('images/Jumbotron-wallpaper.png');
width: 1020px;
max-width: 100%;
height: 431px;
clear: both;
}

.container .content{
text-align: center;
font-family: Arial;
color: #22313f;
}

.container .content h2{
 padding: 20px;
 }

.container .content article{
width: 284px;
margin: 0 auto;
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
padding: 10px
}

.container .content article aside h4{
padding: 10px;
font-size: 1.5em;
}

.container .content article aside p{
width: 100%;
text-align: justify;
padding-top: 10px;
font-weight: bold;
}

.thefooter{
background: #22313f;
min-height: 75px;
margin-top: 75px;
text-align: center;
}

.thefooter p{
padding: 28px;
font-family: Arial;
font-weight: bold;
color: #FFF;
}

@media(min-width: 240px) and (max-width: 768px){

h2.logo{
    float: none;
    text-align: center;
}

#menu-navigation{
    float: none;
    text-align: center;
}

#menu-navigation li{
    display: block;
}

.container .jumbotron{
    background-position: 50%;
}

}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have a link to the website? That will help answering the question!

Comment: its in localhost...

Comment: `max-width: 1020px;` is in your stylesheet, but this is a CSS question not a WordPress question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I resolved it by adding body{padding: 0!important; margin: 0!important}. Didn't know that something was overriding my *{padding: 0; margin: 0;}. Also, forgot to mention that the footer does not belong inside the wrapper which has a max-width of 1020px; because my psd file had the same width.

Comment: I also wanna thank those who contributed some answers.

Answer (score 0):

Your css file clearly shows a max-width of 1020px it appears as if your zoomed out or just on a large screen from your screenshot. If your window is bigger then 1020px then obviously there would be white space on either side.

```
.container{
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1020px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

Also important to note this is not a wordpress issue

Answer (score -1):

Can you please give this in css file to avoid spaces

html, body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

Also yes the container is given max-width of 1020px.

Comment: Can you share the url if you dont mind of not getting the desired output please?